# iOS Instagram API fetch Insights, Engagement, media details

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

How to fetch instagram insights, engagement and media for a particular user. If you search like "instagram stats" in iOS, you could find many apps providing paid service to fetch the following details

1. Most comments by user
2. Least comments by user
3. Most likes by user
4. Least likes by user
5. Most popular media
6. Least popular media
7. Ghost followers
8. Who's interested in me

But instagram official API doesn't provide direct end points to fetch these details. How these many apps providing paid service to get these insights and engagement details ? Are there any open source api's to fetch these data from instagram?? If so please list out here I am implementing a similar stats app and I need these data to be fetched from instagram.

Official API provides follow, unfollow, like, unlike, fetching relationship status like followed by, not following me back, total comments count, total likes count for media.

But how to get the data for the list I mentioned??

Answer (score 0):

To find the engagement rate, you might have to do some manual calculations.

Engagement rate is usually calculated as a portion of your followers. So likes + comments / number of followers. All three of those are endpoints provided by the API. You can calculate this average with PHP once you have the data.

```
$engagementRate = array_sum($totalLikesandComments) / count($followers);
```

You could also use an analytics service to calculate your engagement rate for you. Crowdbabble provides engagement rate and can export data to excel. https://www.crowdbabble.com/blog/how-to-find-your-instagram-engagement-rate/

Comment: Unfortunately instagram is not approving any of these apps... :(